# Data have been cached in Android 6 (SharedPreferences)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I use **SharedPreference** to save **username** after user **login** to my app and **clear** it if user **logout**.

I will check that value when **start** app, if that value null user need **login** to use.

However when I check with **android 6.0**:

```
Login (save username - Toast show not null) > Logout (remove username - Toast show null) > Remove App > Reinstall app > StartApp (not login - Toast show not null, this value is user that used => issue)
```

This issue no occur with **android < 6.0**

Here is my code:

init sharedpreference in Application:

```
public static SharedPreferences getPref() {
    return mInstance.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Check to login:

```
if (App.getPref().getString("username", null) == null){
   //Login
}
```

Save if login success:

```
                App.getPref().edit()
                                .putString("username", s.getLoggedInUser().getUsername())
                                .putString("profilePicUrl", s.getLoggedInUser().getProfilePicUrl())
                                .putString("pk", s.getLoggedInUser().getPk())
                                .apply();
```

Clear when logout:

```
   App.getPref().edit().clear().apply();
```

Comment: exactly what is your problem?

Comment: Please see line 4 in my question with scenario of issue: After I remove app clear sharepreference then reinstall app and read from sharepreference data not null.

Comment: ok got it this is because of Automatic Backups, introduced in M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of Automatic Backups. introduced in Marshmallow .

It will take your data backup and used that backup at the time of reinstall .

**If you want to turn off it from settings -> Backup & reset -> automatic restore**

[image]

But for your app I suggest make the shared pref.

> with key "username" to null at the time of logout
>   and commit.

or Simply make

> `android:allowBackup="false"` in your Manifest

Comment: Hi, @Gaurav. I don't know backup mode in Android 6.0. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, I update my code but the username that backuped before I change backup to false still auto restore. How to remove auto restore from  my code.

Comment: oh , then assigning "username" to null at the tme of  logout , is the only option